# jbpm designer on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, designer, jbpm

I've downloaded jbpm designer war for tomcat from the following link:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/designer/designer-2.4/jbpm-designer-2.4.0.Final-jboss.war/download

I've renamed the WAR to designer and imported it to eclipse, and deployed it to tomcat 6.

Opening:

```
http://localhost:8080/designer/editor.html?profile=jbpm
```

results in a webpage with title @title@ and the content shows: @defaultSkin@ @overlaySkin@

Clearly some servlet is not doing it's magic...

In the web.xml I see the following servlet declaration:

```
 <servlet>
  <display-name>Default Servlet for Directory Listings</display-name>
  <servlet-name>DirectoryListingServlet</servlet-name>
  <!-- <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class> For Tomcat -->
  <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>debug</param-name>
   <param-value>0</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <!-- <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name> for Tomcat -->
   <param-name>listings</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

And although it seems like I should replace the servlet-class with the one in the comment marked for tomcat, doing so just results in ClassNotFoundException (I tried adding some jetty jars according to the exceptions I got, but I didn't know what versions to use, and obviously I ended up with some classes not compliant with expected interfaces).
Anyway, the above servlet is mapped to "/generated-uis/" url-pattern, and actually I don't see any servlet mapped to the url I supply - "/editor.html?profile=jbpm".

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Lior

Answer (score 1):

The correct url should be

```
http://localhost:8080/designer/editor?profile=jbpm
```

don't add the .html to the url